# Constructing an infinite, lazy Monad value recursively

Tags: haskell, recursion, monads, lazy-evaluation, recursive-datastructures

As an exercise, I tried to construct an infinite, lazy list, recursively, inside a monad.

Basically, the equivalent of `nat`, but monadic, `monat`:

```hs
nat :: Int -> [Int]
nat n = n : nat (n+1)

monat :: Monad m => Int -> m [Int]
monat n = return n >>= \n -> (n:) <$> monat (n+1)
```

But `monat` isn't really lazily evaluated: it's impossible to get the first elements without computing it all:

```hs
ghci> take 5 $ nat 0
[0,1,2,3,4]

ghci> take 5 <$> (monat 0) :: Maybe [Int]
... never ending computation ...
```

I suspect the issue must lie in `fmap` or `>>=`, since they're the only extra functions I'm using there but not in `nat`. However I looked at their implementation and I don't see why or where laziness is broken:

```hs
instance  Functor Maybe  where
    fmap _ Nothing       = Nothing
    fmap f (Just a)      = Just (f a)

instance  Monad Maybe  where
    (Just x) >>= k      = k x
    Nothing  >>= _      = Nothing
```

- Can you help me understand why the list in `monat` isn't computed lazily?
- Is there any way to understand why the computation doesn't end, besides analyzing the code? For instance, can I do something like pausing evaluation in GHCi and look at the few latest stack trace frames in order to understand where it's looping? How?

Comment: FYI, `return x >>= f` is just `f x`. So `monat n = (n:) <$> monat (n+1)` would be a more typical definition with the same meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for the infinite loop is simply that `fmap`/`<$>` for the `Maybe` functor needs to know whether the input is `Nothing` or `Just`. Because it only applies the function if there is a `Just` otherwise it will propagate the `Nothing`.

Your function `monat` doesn't specify whether the result should be `Nothing` or `Just`. Both are theoretically fixed points of the equation with which you have defined `monat`. More practically, you can think of it as `monat` postponing the choice between `Nothing` and `Just` every recursive call. In that way, it never actually makes the choice.

One way to resolve this problem while still keeping the monadic interface is to use the `ListT` monad transformer (the one from `list-t`, not the broken one from `transformers` < 0.6 and `mtl` < 2.3). This monad transformer is like a normal list but interspersed with a monad. You can define `monat` like this:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (lift)
import qualified ListT -- from the list-t package
import ListT (ListT)

monat :: Monad m => Int -> ListT m Int
monat n = lift (return n) >>= \m -> cons m (monat (m + 1))
```

And you can use that like this:

```
ghci> ListT.toList (ListT.take 5 (monat 0) :: ListT Maybe Int)
Just [0,1,2,3,4]
```